# R - how to return the second to last/previous value in data file

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to compare the most recent value in a data frame, with the previous value and can't figure it out. Is there a tail command that returns the previous to last value??

I'm trying to return the value that was before the last bar;

```
2014-08-21 21:00:00             77.80724

tail(stock)

                           minutes.Close
2014-08-20 20:00:00             76.06327
2014-08-20 21:05:00             73.51396
2014-08-21 11:00:00             74.11548
2014-08-21 16:00:00             77.13998
2014-08-21 21:00:00             77.80724
2014-08-21 23:20:00             77.86165

tail(stock, n=1)
                           minutes.Close
2014-08-21 23:20:00             77.86165
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
head(tail(stock, n=2),1)
```

or

```
stock[nrow(stock)-1, ]
```